# Eclipse RCP: ClassNotFoundException or How to make other bundle load my class

Tags: reflection, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Details: I'm trying to use Jalapeno framework to connect my RCP app with Cache' database. After connection established, I'm trying to get all data from table exactly like in Jalapeno manual:

```java
if (objManager==null) return;
DBClass cortege = null;
try {
Iterator terms = objManager.openByQuery(DBClass.class, null, null);
System.out.println("terms ok");
while (terms.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("has next");
    cortege = (DBClass)terms.next();
}
```

this code compiling, running and trowing exception

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: myPluginId.views.DBClass
at com.intersys.objects.POJOIterator.next(POJOIterator.java:75)
   ...skip...
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myPlugin.views.DBClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:129)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.jalapeno.runtime.ObjectCopierToPojo.detach(ObjectCopierToPojo.java:76)
    at com.jalapeno.runtime.ObjectCopierToPojo.findPojo(ObjectCopierToPojo.java:472)
    at com.intersys.classes.CacheRootObject.detach(CacheRootObject.java:255)
    at com.intersys.classes.Persistent.detach(Persistent.java:567)
    at com.intersys.objects.POJOIterator.next(POJOIterator.java:59)
```

at terms.next();

I can't get it at all... instance of class DBClass was just created, but class cannot be loaded.
**then I've tried to place this code in simple java application (not eclipse rcp) and all went ok.** so I think some Eclipse part blocking class loading.

also i've tried to load class before calling terms.next();

```java
Bundle b = Platform.getBundle("myPluginId");
try {
b.loadClass("DBClass");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("no class");
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...and got same error. Class can not be loaded.
So, is it a known problem? Is there a solution?

#### Update

After some research updating the question:

How to make Jalapeno plugin to load class from My plugin?

Comment: in eclipse google group found, that Jalapeno plugin and my class must be loaded by same class loader... i don't know how to do this.

Comment: is it what I need? http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/BundleProxyClassLoader_recipe
if yes, how to use it?

Comment: take a look at my answer below, but yes, I believe you need buddy class loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try buddy classloading. For more info on Eclipse classloading, Alex Blewitt has written an excellent overview of the classloading system in Eclipse [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/).  Its a few years old, but for the most part it is still relevant.

The jist of buddy classloading is this:

- a plugin declares that it needs help loading classes.  It does this by declaring its "buddy plugin"
- the buddy plugin declares its buddy policy
- when the regular loading mechanism fails, Eclipse tries to use the buddy classloading policies you have specified.

So in your case, try putting:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
```

in your Jalapeno plugin's manifest.mf file

and put:

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: id.of.jalepeno.plugin
```

in the manifest.mf of your plugin

Comment: thanks! It helped! Just one thing: is there a way to improve performance, to skip regular mechanism (I suppose it iterates all classes in Jalapeno plugin) and use buddy-loading first (only in expected places... I mean where I know buddy loading will occur)?

Comment: glad it helped!  But for second question, I can't think of any ways of the top of my head on how to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you have to export the package in which the classes are lying.

Select in the MANIFEST "Runtime" and add all packages